# How to add quotation marks around selected text in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Countless times i have needed to put a quotation marks around text during programming. I remember awhile ago that i have seen someone selecting text and simply do magic with the keyboard shortcuts and putting quotation marks around it. How to do so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In eclipse

```
1. Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates
2. Click on "New"
3. Type "quote" for name (you can name it whatever you want)
4. In the pattern box, enter "${word_selection}"${cursor}
5. Click ok
6. Click apply and close preferences
7. Select the string you want quoted, press CTRL + <space> and type quote
```

Comment: not the type of solution i expected , but working as it needed to! Does windows OS support that kind of shortcut at all?

Comment: This functionality is provided by eclipse. It doesn't matter what OS you use. I tested in eclipse on windows and it works

Comment: i know , i meant to ask if there is supported kind of shortcut by windows perhaps i want to use it on notepad? like the ctrl+v etc..

Comment: Eclipse is so dumb sometimes, every decent editor would surround a string selection with the quotes you just start entering.