# Shortcut to put hyphens around selection in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a quick and easy way to transform a selected `text` into `"text"`. If you just press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> on selected text, the text will be replaced by " and not enclosed ".

Same question for different IDE (Visual Studio)

> [Is there a way to put double quotes around selected text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752551/is-there-a-way-to-put-double-quotes-around-selected-text)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28347763/8881141

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add quotation marks around selected text in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347763/how-to-add-quotation-marks-around-selected-text-in-eclipse)

Comment: Ok, that describes my question. However, the solution doesn't work. My template is not shown in the dropdown when text is selected but only if nothing is selected. But then the template is worthless. I suggest, there is no solution at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried to ask the [Eclipse forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/)? I bet there are people, who know, how to define [this specific key binding](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F). Please post the solution afterwards here as well.